# MySQL An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, azure

I am currently writing an application with Microsoft Azure. Currently, I have been successfully able to create tables, insert into them, etc. However, when selecting I encountered a problem.

When I tried to select, it gave me the error

> "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.".

I have tried looking at all access permissions but am lost in general.

Does anybody have an idea? The PHP statement is a simple `Select * from DATABASE`, and the connection to the database is successful.

Comment: A [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22An+attempt+was+made+to+access+a+socket+in+a+way+forbidden+by+its+access+permissions.%22.&rlz=1C1GTPM___US647US648&oq=%22An+attempt+was+made+to+access+a+socket+in+a+way+forbidden+by+its+access+permissions.%22.&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2155j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) reveals a lot of information.

Comment: Could you tell me what the `PHP+MySQL` deployment environment is? Is it an Azure PHP webapp with MySQL? or an PHP webapp with a standalone ClearDB instance? or the MySQL hosted on Azure VM? And please supply the related source code to reproduce the problem for troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: It is the first one, an Azure PHP webapp with MySQL. You can find any relevant source code here: pastebin.com/DfkWUuxB. Any and all help is appreciated ! @PeterPan-MSFT

Comment: Could you tell me how you were able to insert data into the databases? Im making PUT requests to a php file. Where do I place the PHP file, like in which folder on Azure? I could really use some help @KillianO'Connor

Comment: @JayBlanchard Quite ironic that I performed that exact search. The first result was this SO question, and the first comment below the question was yours telling me to do exactly what I'd done.

Answer (score 0):

The error information signify that there are some things conflict with each other in your code.
It seems that the issue was caused by MySQL Native Driver `MySQLi`.

There are two group functions `mysql_*` & `mysqli_*` in your code for MySQL connecting or querying.

I searched that the SO thread [Connection with mysqli() does not work, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419337/connection-with-mysqli-does-not-work-why) might be the solution for the issue. Try to only use the one of them for avoiding possible confliction.

And according to the Azure offical document for `PHP+MySQL`, you can try to use `PDO` instead of `MySQLi`.

Hope it helps. Best Regards.